# <f:param envia id null e é lançado java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: jsf-2.2

utilizo o mesmo formulário de cadastro para atualizar um registro do datatable. ao clicar em atualizar ele envia para o inputText o nome a ser atualizado até aqui tudo bem, o problema é quando o nome é alterado e o botão é clicado. o inputText volta para o nome anterior e a alteração não ocorre.

Notei que a exceção é lançada quando o link de editar é clicado! e o dado vai para o inputText para ser editado. Quando o nome é alterado e clicado no botão salvar o nome voltar ao original e não salva nada aí altera o nome novamente e clica em salvar aí o nome é alterado! ou seja tem que fazer mais de uma vez para alterar um dado.

Dei um System.out.println(params.get("id") + " "+ params.containsValue("id")); antes da linha que levanta a exceção e retornou null, false .

Então o `<f:param` não está enviando o valor do id para o MangedBean.

É como se o "id" que vem da view através do atributo param estivesse enviando sempre nulo!

Como posso resolver isso?

**Página**

```
     <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Editar" />
            </f:facet>

            <f:ajax event="click" render="@all"
                listener="#{localidadeBean.preparaAlteracao}">

                <h:commandLink>
                    <f:param name="id" value="#{localidade.codLocalidade}" />
                    <h:graphicImage title="editar" library="imagens" name="editar.png"
                        style="float:right;" />
                </h:commandLink>

            </f:ajax>               

        </h:column>
```

**ManagedBean**

```
public void preparaAlteracao() {
    Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

    Integer id = Integer.parseInt(params.get("id"));// Linha que levanta a Exceção

    facade = new Facade(this.getManager());
    try {
        this.localidade = facade.procuraLocalidade(id);
    } catch (RepositorioException e) {
        BaseBean.addErrorMessage("localidade", e.getMessage());
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("localidade", e.getMessage()));
    }
}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
    Out 17, 2014 5:56:12 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
Advertência: /lista-de-localidades.xhtml @34,53 listener="#    {localidadeBean.preparaAlteracao}": java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
javax.el.ELException: /lista-de-localidades.xhtml @34,53 listener="#{localidadeBean.preparaAlteracao}": java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:111)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxHandler.java:447)
at javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent.processListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent.java:113)
at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:106)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:760)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1092)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:795)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1260)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at br.com.sescpe.scontratos.controle.filtro.JPAFilter.doFilter(JPAFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at br.com.sescpe.scontratos.controle.filtro.ControleAcesso.doFilter(ControleAcesso.java:37)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
at java.lang.Integer.<init>(Integer.java:677)
at br.com.sescpe.scontratos.controle.managedbean.localidade.LocalidadeBean.preparaAlteracao(LocalidadeBean.java:94)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
... 36 more
```

Comment: Não entendi uma coisa, nesse `CommandLink` está chamando o método `preparaAlteracao` do seu Bean? Além disso ele está dentro de um `dataTable`? Poderia incluir o código mais completo?

Comment: Sim. ao clicar no `commandLink` o `<f:param` deveria pegar o id da linha selecionada e enviar para o método `preparaAlteracao()` que recebe o id e faz um parseInt já que recebe uma `String` e tem que converter para `Integer`

Comment: postei o código da coluna editar. O detalhe é que para remover uma linha do `datatable` faço da mesma maneira e não tenho problema.

Answer (score 3):

Depois de 5 meses descobrir a solução de um problema que me atormentava:

### Solução:

- Desabilitar o Ajax do *link* editar.
- No form de cadastro tinha o atributo `required = "true"` para evitar o cadastro de valores vazios. Com `required = "true"`  o item do registro não era enviado ao campo para ser alterado e a mensagem de preenchimento obrigatório era chamada (após desabilitar o Ajax no *link* editar). Ao colocar `required = "false"` o item do registro vai para o campo para ser alterado e mudar o item para outro nome este é editado de primeira. Não acontece mas de voltar para o item anterior e colocar o novo nome novamente para editar.

Agora como nem tudo são flores, o formulário pode cadastrar valores vazios! Aí tive que tratar isto no MB.

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro uma reestruturação, para não depender de atributos de requisição, que podem ser facilmente perdidos ou esquecidos.

No caso, você pode usar o `f:ajax` para adicionar a funcionalidade de Ajax, mas mantendo o `action` no `commandLink` e usar o objeto `localidade` pelo escopo que o `dataTable` cria em vez de usar um `f:param`.

A organização ficaria assim:

**Facelets**

```
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Editar" />
    </f:facet>

    <h:commandLink action="#{localidadeBean.preparaAlteracao(localidade)}">
        <f:ajax render="@all" />
        <h:graphicImage title="editar" library="imagens" name="editar.png" style="float:right;" />
    </h:commandLink>
</h:column>
```

Acredito que o `dataTable` tem um `var` com nome "localidade". Além disso fiz a troca pelo `action`, se quiser pode usar o `actionListener` sem problema.

O `f:ajax` por padrão vai usar o evento principal do `commandLink` que é o *click*.

**Managed Bean**

```
public void preparaAlteracao(Localidade localidade) {
    Integer id = localidade.getCodLocalidade();

    facade = new Facade(this.getManager());

    try {
        this.localidade = facade.procuraLocalidade(id);
    } catch (RepositorioException e) {
        BaseBean.addErrorMessage("localidade", e.getMessage());
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("localidade", e.getMessage()));
    }
}
```

Ainda é possível evitar de chamar o seu `Facade` para buscar o objeto, usando apenas o objeto passado por parâmetro. Só que ai depende da origem do objeto e se ele tem os dados que você precisa mais adiante.

Answer (score 0):

Estava testando as alternativas para passagem de valor da página para o bean:

1º `<f:param>`

2º `<f:attribute>`

3º `<f:setPropertyActionListener>`

4º Passagem de Parametro:
`<h:commandLink actionListener="#{localidadeBean.atualiza(localidade)}">`

A 1º opção é a única que gera a exceção e era que eu estava usando.

A 2º opção no bean recebe como parametro um ActionEvent deve ser AJAX apesar de que na página não está passando nada(Não entendo isso) e na página fica sublinhado de vermelho.(ERRO)

A 3º opção posso passar o objeto (linha) e setar o objeto no bean e não precisa acessar o banco :)

A 4º opção é parecida com a 3º só que tive que criar um método com o mesmo corpo do set do objeto e na página fica sublinhado de vermelho.(ERRO).

Todas funcionam, mas o usuário tem que fazer a operação 2 vezes para alterar o item. Não sei o porquê.

Escolhi a 3ª por ser a mais vantajosa em questão de implementação.

Comment: Ainda sim,  gostaria de saber porque não altera o registro assim que clico em salvar na primeira tentativa e retorna o nome atual do registro no inputText, então tenho que apagar o nome atual digitar novamente o nome que quero e clicar novamente em salvar para o nome no campo seja alterado.